# Passing a WebKit Session to Another View Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently able to enter my username and password into my IOS app and hit login which populates the inputs I made into my website and takes me to my discussion board. A brief code example is as follows:

```
import WebKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    //I removed all the username and password fields and labels for easier reading

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTap()
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
        let url = URL(string: "https://gmail.com")!
        webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 300, height: 300)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        //webView.isHidden = true
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    //Action for when button is hit

    @objc func loginAction() {  
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('username_field').value='\(usernameTextField.text!)'", completionHandler: nil)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('password_field').value='\(passwordTextField.text!)'", completionHandler: nil)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('loginbutton', '', true, '', '', false, true))", completionHandler: { (value, error) in
        })

}
```

now since I am not using a storyboard I normally push to another view controller with this code:

```
    let discussionController = DiscussionController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(discussionController, animated: true)
```

Here is my question, after I login and go to another view controller I want the web view session to stay active. Im not sure if I would have to make a separate "class" just for the webView and its only referenced for data when needed? or if I can send over the webView to the separate view controller when pushing into it. If anyone has any ideas they would be much appreciated!